# jquery mobile application works in chrome simulator but not in actual device

Tags: jquery-mobile

We have a ASP.net web application integrated with DotNetNuke.
The mobile version uses jQuery mobile 1.6.X.

While trying to test the application it works well in Chrome simulator(our staging environment is publicly exposed). But it does not work in any of the actual device.

Can anyone suggest how to debug this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android you can attach the device to the pc and go to `chrome-> developer tools -> inspect devices`

Make sure your phone is set to developers mode with usb debugging on.

For iOS you can attach your phone to a mac and open safari, develop menu and then the device you want to inspect.

There you will find the javascript console, source, style and everything you normally need for website debugging.